# Error: could not find or load main class newClass JVM

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, jvm, package

In the directory:

`/home/ThinkPinkApp/flocks`

I have the following two source files:

`FlockingInformation.java   FlockLists.java`

at the top of each source file I have

`package home.ThinkPinkApp.flocks`

Compiling the files causes no issue, however, when I attempt to run the main methods for each file, I receive the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class FlockingInformation Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: home/ThinkPinkApp/flocks/FlockingInformation (wrong name: FlockingInformation)`

Compiling and running the files in my home directory `~/ThinkPinkApp/objects` without the package keyword is fine and causes no issue. When I add `package objects` to the same sources files in my home directory though I receive the same error.

I have attempted to use the -CLASSPATH option with the java command, and still receive the same error. I have read the official oracle documentation regarding the java command and am unsure of what I am doing wrong. My understanding is that the JVM looks for files in the current directory by default, so why isn't it able to find/load these classes? I understand that the JVM also uses the class path variable, but I am unsure how to access/change that. and even then I should be able to use the -cp option to manually change what directories it looks in right?

I have also attempted running the files with `java home.ThinkPinkApp.FlockingInformation` this produces a similar error, minus the `(wrong name: FlockingInformation)` part. Unsure of what this means though.

Any explanation or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, Java sources and classes need to be stored in such a way that the directory hierarchy matches the package hierarchy. If you want to run class `home.Foo`, the class file must be in a directory `home`. Then either the current directory should be the one that contains `home`, or $CLASSPATH needs to reference the directory that contains `home`.

Using the `-d` switch to `javac` will control the directory where compiled classes are written. When this switch is given, the directory structure will automatically be created so that it matches the package structure, so you shouldn't need to fiddle about moving the `.class` files around manually.

There's a detailed discussion of these issues here:

[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)